# Mysql LEFT JOIN in combination with optional relation parent<->child table not working

Tags: mysql, left-join

I am having some troubles when combining left joins with optional values to group by.

In short we have

1. table child products: catalog
2. table parent relations - if it exists! contains parent child relations : catalog_product_relation
3. table warehouses : warehouses
4. table products and stock : wh_products

and we are trying to get the stock total qty, where

- stock is stored by child products and needs to be summed per that
- if a parent relation exists then we should group by and show that data

even simpler

- for products without a parent: just sum qty (already works)
- for products with a parent: then rollup and sum by the parent identifier
- and preferably also get the data for the parent identifier from the catalog (ie the right name and sku)

I hope it is clear ... the query below is not working. Step 1 to me looked like just getting the parent ID in a column

and step 2 is to sum the qty's for simple products per simple product and for parent products sum it up for *all* child simple product but show the parent data

```
select c.sku as sku,
 IFNULL(pr.parent_id, c.entity_id) as main_id,
 c.type_id as type,
 SUM(CASE WHEN (wh.code='LR') THEN FLOOR(wp.qty) ELSE 0 END) AS 'Loc1',
 SUM(CASE WHEN (wh.code='LS') THEN FLOOR(wp.qty) ELSE 0 END) AS 'Loc2'
 FROM catalog c,
 wh_products wp,
 warehouses wh
 LEFT JOIN catalog_product_relation pr ON pr.parent_id = c.entity_id
 WHERE c.entity_id = wp.product_id and wp.warehouse_id = wh.warehouse_id and wp.qty > 0 
GROUP BY main_id
```

Answer (score 0):

I would start by writing the `JOIN`s correctly and aggregating by the columns in the `SELECT`:

```
SELECT c.sku as sku,
       COALESCE(pr.parent_id, c.entity_id) as main_id, c.type_id as type,
       SUM(CASE WHEN wh.code = 'LR' THEN FLOOR(wp.qty) ELSE 0 END) AS Loc1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN wh.code = 'LS' THEN FLOOR(wp.qty) ELSE 0 END) AS Loc2
FROM catalog c LEFT JOIN
     wh_products wp
     ON c.entity_id = wp.product_id LEFT JOIN
     warehouses wh
     ON wp.warehouse_id = wh.warehouse_id AND wp.qty > 0 LEFT JOIN
     catalog_product_relation pr
     ON pr.parent_id = c.entity_id
GROUP BY c.sku, COALESCE(pr.parent_id, c.entity_id), c.type_id;
```

I'm not sure if this fixes your problems.  Without sample data and desired results, it is a bit hard to follow the logic.